# Parametrizing tests depending of also parametrized values in pytest

Tags: unit-testing, pytest, fixtures

I have a test where I have a setup method, that should receive a *dataset*, and a test function, that should run for each *data* in *dataset*

Basically I would need something like:

```
datasetA = [data1_a, data2_a, data3_a]
datasetB = [data1_b, data2_b, data3_b]

@pytest.fixture(autouse=True, scope="module", params=[datasetA, datasetB])
def setup(dataset):
    #do setup
    yield
    #finalize

#dataset should be the same instantiated for the setup
@pytest.mark.parametrize('data', [data for data in dataset]) 
def test_data(data):
    #do test
```

It should run like:

- setup(datasetA)
- test(data1_a)
- test(data2_a)
- test(data3_a)
- setup(datasetB)
- test(data1_b)
- test(data2_b)
- test(data3_b)

However it does not seem to be possible to parametrize over a variable obtained by a fixture, as I wanted to in the example.

I could have my function use a fixture and iterate inside the test method:

```
def test_data(dataset):
    for data in dataset:
        #do test
```

But then I would have one large test instead of a separate test for each case, which I would not like to have.

Is there any way of accomplishing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answer #1: If strictly following you test design, then it should look like this:

```
import pytest

datasetA = [10, 20, 30]
datasetB = [100, 200, 300]

@pytest.fixture
def dataset(request):
    #do setup
    items = request.param
    yield items
    #finalize

@pytest.fixture
def item(request, dataset):
    index = request.param
    yield dataset[index]

#dataset should be the same instantiated for the setup
@pytest.mark.parametrize('dataset', [datasetA, datasetB], indirect=True)
@pytest.mark.parametrize('item', [0, 1, 2], indirect=True)
def test_data(dataset, item):
    print(item)
    #do test
```

Note the indirect parametrization for both `item` & `dataset`. The parameter values will be passed to the same-named fixture as `request.param`. In this case, we use the index in the assumption that the datasets are of the same length of 3 items.

Here is how it executes:

```
$ pytest -s -v -ra test_me.py 
test_me.py::test_data[0-dataset0] 10
PASSED
test_me.py::test_data[0-dataset1] 100
PASSED
test_me.py::test_data[1-dataset0] 20
PASSED
test_me.py::test_data[1-dataset1] 200
PASSED
test_me.py::test_data[2-dataset0] 30
PASSED
test_me.py::test_data[2-dataset1] 300
PASSED
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this code actually calls setup for each test, while I need to run setup only once for each dataset.

Comment: Actually changing dataset annotation to `@pytest.fixture(scope="module", params=[datasetA,datasetB])` and removing the line `@pytest.mark.parametrize('dataset', [datasetA, datasetB], indirect=True)` does the trick. However, the item parametrization based on the index is ugly and doesn't take into account that the datasets might have different sizes. Is there a solution for this?

Comment: Actually I forgot to specify in the question that I would like the setup to run only once. Will edit it!

Comment: Note that this answer relies on the fact that both datasets have the same number of items and therefore can be parametrized with the same `index` parameter equal to `range(3)`. For a more generic answer see https://stackoverflow.com/a/62818423/7262247

Answer (score 2):

The answer from [Sergey](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46919449/7262247) seems incomplete to me as it relies on the fact that both datasets have the same number of items and therefore can be parametrized with the same `index` parameter equal to `range(3)`.

Here is another more generic answer allowing each database to have its own number of items. It uses the new version 2.0.0 of [`pytest-cases`](https://smarie.github.io/python-pytest-cases/) that has been vastly improved over the legacy one (I let my old answer on this page as it talks about some other/additional concerns):

```
from pytest_cases import parametrize_with_cases, parametrize, fixture

datasetA = [10, 20, 30]
dbA_keys = range(3)

datasetB = [100, 200]  # just to see that it works with different sizes :)
dbB_keys = range(2)

@fixture(scope="module")
def dbA():
    #do setup
    yield datasetA
    #finalize

@parametrize(idx=dbA_keys)
def item_from_A(dbA, idx):
    yield dbA[idx]

@fixture(scope="module")
def dbB():
    #do setup
    yield datasetB
    #finalize

@parametrize(idx=dbB_keys)
def item_from_B(dbB, idx):
    yield dbB[idx]

@parametrize_with_cases('data', prefix='item_', cases='.')
def test_data(data):
    print(data)
    #do test
```

Much simpler don't you think ?

Answer (score 1):

Answer #2: You can also inject into the collection & parametrization stage of pytest via the pseudo-plugin named `conftest.py` in the current directory:

`conftest.py`:

```
import pytest

datasetA = [100, 200, 300]
datasetB = [10, 20, 30]

def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
    if 'data' in metafunc.fixturenames:
        for datasetname, dataset in zip(['A', 'B'], [datasetA, datasetB]):
            for data in dataset:
                metafunc.addcall(dict(data=data), id=datasetname+str(data))
```

`test_me.py`:

```
def test_data(data):
    print(data)
    #do test
```

Run:

```
$ pytest -ra -v -s test_me.py 

test_me.py::test_data[A100] 100
PASSED
test_me.py::test_data[A200] 200
PASSED
test_me.py::test_data[A300] 300
PASSED
test_me.py::test_data[B10] 10
PASSED
test_me.py::test_data[B20] 20
PASSED
test_me.py::test_data[B30] 30
PASSED
```

However, making `dataset` indirect (i.e. accessible via the fixture with the setup & teardown stages) becomes difficult here, since `metafunc.addcall()` does nt support indirect parameters.

---

The only way to add the `indirect=...` is via `metafunc.parametrize()`. But in that case, assuming that the datasets are of different sizes, you will have to build the whole list of dataset-dataitem pairs:

`conftest.py`:

```
import pytest

datasetA = [100, 200, 300]
datasetB = [10, 20, 30]
datasets = [datasetA, datasetB]

def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
    if 'data' in metafunc.fixturenames:
        metafunc.parametrize('dataset, data', [
            (dataset, data)
            for dataset in datasets
            for data in dataset
        ], indirect=['dataset'], ids=[
            'DS{}-{}'.format(idx, str(data))
            for idx, dataset in enumerate(datasets)
            for data in dataset
        ])

@pytest.fixture()
def dataset(request):
    #do setup
    yield request.param
    #finalize
```

`test_me.py`:

```
def test_data(dataset, data):
    print(data)
    #do test
```

Run:

```
$ pytest -ra -v -s test_me.py 

test_me.py::test_data[DS0-100] 100
PASSED
test_me.py::test_data[DS0-200] 200
PASSED
test_me.py::test_data[DS0-300] 300
PASSED
test_me.py::test_data[DS1-10] 10
PASSED
test_me.py::test_data[DS1-20] 20
PASSED
test_me.py::test_data[DS1-30] 30
PASSED
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT: this is an old answer using a legacy version of pytest-cases. Please look at [this new answer instead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62818423/7262247)**

`pytest-cases` offers two ways to solve this problem

- `@cases_data`, a decorator that you can use on your test function or fixture so that it sources its parameters from various "case functions", possibly in various modules, and possibly themselve parametrized. The problem is that "case functions" are not fixtures, and therefore do not allow you to benefit from the dependencies and setup/teardown mechanism. I use it rather to collect various cases from file system.
- more recent but more 'pytest-y', `fixture_union` allows you to create a fixture that is the union of two or more fixtures. This includes setup/teardown and dependencies, so it is what you would prefer here. You can create a union either explicitly or by using `pytest_parametrize_plus` with `fixture_ref()` in the parameter values.

Here is how your example would look:

```
import pytest
from pytest_cases import pytest_parametrize_plus, pytest_fixture_plus, fixture_ref

# ------ Dataset A
DA = ['data1_a', 'data2_a', 'data3_a']
DA_data_indices = list(range(len(DA)))

@pytest_fixture_plus(scope="module")
def datasetA():
    print("setting up dataset A")
    yield DA
    print("tearing down dataset A")

@pytest_fixture_plus(scope="module")
@pytest.mark.parametrize('data_index', DA_data_indices, ids="idx={}".format)
def data_from_datasetA(datasetA, data_index):
    return datasetA[data_index]

# ------ Dataset B
DB = ['data1_b', 'data2_b']
DB_data_indices = list(range(len(DB)))

@pytest_fixture_plus(scope="module")
def datasetB():
    print("setting up dataset B")
    yield DB
    print("tearing down dataset B")

@pytest_fixture_plus(scope="module")
@pytest.mark.parametrize('data_index', range(len(DB)), ids="idx={}".format)
def data_from_datasetB(datasetB, data_index):
    return datasetB[data_index]

# ------ Test
@pytest_parametrize_plus('data', [fixture_ref('data_from_datasetA'),
                                  fixture_ref('data_from_datasetB')])
def test_databases(data):
    # do test
    print(data)
```

Of course, you may wish to handle any number of datasets dynamically. In that case you have to generate all alternative fixtures dynamically, because pytest has to know in advance what is the number of tests to execute. This works quite well:

```
import pytest
from makefun import with_signature

from pytest_cases import pytest_parametrize_plus, pytest_fixture_plus, fixture_ref

# ------ Datasets
datasets = {
    'DA': ['data1_a', 'data2_a', 'data3_a'],
    'DB': ['data1_b', 'data2_b']
}
datasets_indices = {dn: range(len(dc)) for dn, dc in datasets.items()}


# ------ Datasets fixture generation
def create_dataset_fixture(dataset_name):
    @pytest_fixture_plus(scope="module", name=dataset_name)
    def dataset():
        print("setting up dataset %s" % dataset_name)
        yield datasets[dataset_name]
        print("tearing down dataset %s" % dataset_name)

    return dataset

def create_data_from_dataset_fixture(dataset_name):
    @pytest_fixture_plus(name="data_from_%s" % dataset_name, scope="module")
    @pytest.mark.parametrize('data_index', dataset_indices, ids="idx={}".format)
    @with_signature("(%s, data_index)" % dataset_name)
    def data_from_dataset(data_index, **kwargs):
        dataset = kwargs.popitem()[1]
        return dataset[data_index]

    return data_from_dataset

for dataset_name, dataset_indices in datasets_indices.items():
    globals()[dataset_name] = create_dataset_fixture(dataset_name)
    globals()["data_from_%s" % dataset_name] = create_data_from_dataset_fixture(dataset_name)

# ------ Test
@pytest_parametrize_plus('data', [fixture_ref('data_from_%s' % n)
                                  for n in datasets_indices.keys()])
def test_databases(data):
    # do test
    print(data)
```

Both provide the same output:

```
setting up dataset DA
data1_a
data2_a
data3_a
tearing down dataset DA
setting up dataset DB
data1_b
data2_b
tearing down dataset DB
```

EDIT: there might be a simpler solution if the setup/teardown procedure is the same for all datasets, with using `param_fixtures`. I'll try to post that soon.

EDIT 2: actually the simpler solution I was referring to seems to lead to multiple setup/teardown as you already noted in the accepted answer:

```
from pytest_cases import pytest_fixture_plus, param_fixtures

# ------ Datasets
datasets = {
    'DA': ['data1_a', 'data2_a', 'data3_a'],
    'DB': ['data1_b', 'data2_b']
}

was_setup = {
    'DA': False,
    'DB': False
}

data_indices = {_dataset_name: list(range(len(_dataset_contents)))
                for _dataset_name, _dataset_contents in datasets.items()}

param_fixtures("dataset_name, data_index", [(_dataset_name, _data_idx) for _dataset_name in datasets
                                            for _data_idx in data_indices[_dataset_name]],
               scope='module')

@pytest_fixture_plus(scope="module")
def dataset(dataset_name):
    print("setting up dataset %s" % dataset_name)
    assert not was_setup[dataset_name]
    was_setup[dataset_name] = True
    yield datasets[dataset_name]
    print("tearing down dataset %s" % dataset_name)

@pytest_fixture_plus(scope="module")
def data(dataset, data_index):
    return dataset[data_index]

# ------ Test
def test_databases(data):
    # do test
    print(data)
```

I opened a ticket on pytest-dev to better understand why: [pytest-dev#5457](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/5457)

See [documentation](https://smarie.github.io/python-pytest-cases/) for details. (I'm the author by the way) )