# Use pytest.lazy_fixture list values as parameters in another fixture

Tags: python, automated-tests, pytest, fixtures

Im trying to use list of one fixture values as parameters into another. Here is my setup:

```
import pytest

d = {
    "first": [1, 2, 3],
    "second": [4, 5, 6]
}

@pytest.fixture(params=['first', 'second'])
def foo(request):
    return d.get(request.param)

@pytest.fixture(params=[pytest.lazy_fixture('foo')])
def bar(request):
    return request.param

def test_1(bar):
    pass
```

The problem is `bar()` always get full list as `request.param` ([1, 2, 3] not values of the list. If in `params` of `bar()` fixture send data directly, e.g:

```
@pytest.fixture(params=[1, 2, 3])
def bar(request):
    return request.param

def test_1(bar):
    pass
```

Then argument request will work properly (test starts three times). The same situation, if I pass arguments to `params` not directly, but from any method without fixture decorator, i.e:

```
def some():
    return [1, 2, 3]

@pytest.fixture(params=some())
def more(request):
    return request.param

def test_2(more):
    logging.error(more)
    pass
```

So, my question is it possible to obtain data from list one by one and then use it in my test? I've try to 'unparse' list:

```
@pytest.fixture(params=[i for i in i pytest.lazy_fixture('foo')])
def bar(request):
    return request.param
```

But in this case I get `TypeError: 'LazyFixture' object is not iterable`

Comment: grmmvv, Did you get the workaround to above problem?

Answer (score 4):

See [this answer to a very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56865893/7262247): by design, fixture values can not be used as lists of parameters to parametrize tests. Indeed parameters are resolved at pytest collection phase, while, fixtures are resolved later, during pytest nodes execution.

The best that you can do with [`lazy_fixture`](https://github.com/TvoroG/pytest-lazy-fixture) or with `pytest_cases.fixture_ref` is to use a **single** fixture value as a parameter. With `lazy_fixture` you have limitations (if I remember correctly, the fixture cannot be parametrized) while with [`pytest_cases`](https://smarie.github.io/python-pytest-cases/) you can do pretty much anything (using the `fixture_ref` in a parameter tuple, using several `fixture_ref`s each with different parametrization, etc.). I'm the author of `pytest_cases` by the way ;)

See also [this thread](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/349).

Comment: Great answer ! thanks

Comment: [smaire] my problem is that I want to parameterize a fixture with comma-separated values passed as a custom command line argument I added. So I need to parameterize a fixture (not test) with another fixture. Will this come under phase B.