# Pytest: How to parametrize a test with a list that is returned from a fixture?

Tags: python, pytest

I want to parametrize a test with a list which is created dynamically by a fixture like so:

```
@pytest.fixture
def my_list_returning_fixture(depends_on_other_fixtures):
    return ["a dynamically created list which", depends_on_other_fixtures]
```

How can I achieve that? Alternatively, how can I ensure that [a certain fixture gets called first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52765085/pytest-how-to-make-sure-a-certain-fixture-is-called-first) - this would solve this problem before it even occurs.

---

#### What I already tried

- I tried to parametrize the test with the fixture (which just results in errors because python thinks I want to hand over the function itself):

  ```
  @pytest.mark.parametrize(
      "an_element_from_the_list_of_my_fixture", 
      my_list_returning_fixture
  )
  def test_the_list(an_element_from_the_list_of_my_fixture):
      print(an_element_from_the_list_of_my_fixture)
  ```

  Calling the fixture like a normal function like `my_list_returning_fixture()` just results in errors, too! Python doesn't know how to fill the "parameters" of the fixture (which are actually just other fixtures) and displays an error message about too few passed arguments...

  Therefore I need pytest to inject the `depends_on_other_fixtures` dependencies, so I can't call it like a normal function.
- I also tried to interpose another fixture between the list fixture and the test like so:

  ```
  @pytest.fixture(params=my_list_returning_fixture)
  def my_interposed_parametrized_fixture(request):
      return request.param

  def test_the_list(my_interposed_parametrized_fixture):
      ...
  ```
- I also tried to play around with indirect parametrization but it didn't work either...

---

#### It's easy with static lists

I know it is easily possible to parametrize a test with a given `list` like so:

```
the_list = [1, 2, 3]
@pytest.mark.parametrize("an_element_from_the_list", the_list)
def test_the_list(an_element_from_the_list):
    print(an_element_from_the_list)
```

This will lead to three tests. One for each element in the list.

Comment: Same problem as in your other question - when evaluating fixture/test parameters in `fixture`/`mark.parametrize` decorators, no fixture has executed yet and there are no fixture results in the internal cache. If the fixture has no other dependencies, the straightforward workaround is to simply call the fixture as a plain function, e.g. `@pytest.mark.parametrize('arg', fixturefunc())`, but that's not your case.

Comment: BTW, there is an old [open issue](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/349) for passing fixtures to `mark.parametrize` as parameters.

Comment: @hoefling. And it looks like it won't be resolved any time soon: https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/2155

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The short answer is that you can't do it the way you want, i.e., through fixtures: https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/2155. Basically, the number of things yielded or returned has to be known up front for pytest to properly compute the fixture and test dependency graph.

It appears that the only way is to fix the list elements before passing them to any of pytests's decorators. Here is an example, related to your other question, showing that the problem can not be solved by say a generator:

```
import pytest

def gen_lines():
    with open('file_that_does_not_exist') as f:
        yield from f

@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def create_file():
    with open('file_that_does_not_exist', 'w') as f:
        print('ABC', file=f)
        print('DEF', file=f)

@pytest.fixture(params=gen_lines())
def line_fixture(request):
    return request.param

def test_line(line_fixture):
    assert True
```

This will fail at collection time when pytest turns your generator into a list. Adding a dependency to `line_fixture` on `create_file` won't help either for the same reason.

Your only real option at this point is to run `create_file` at module load time or before.

```
import pytest

def gen_lines():
    with open('file_that_does_not_exist') as f:
        yield from f

def create_file():
    with open('file_that_does_not_exist', 'w') as f:
        print('ABC', file=f)
        print('DEF', file=f)

create_file()

@pytest.fixture(params=gen_lines())
def line_fixture(request):
    return request.param

def test_line(line_fixture):
    assert True
```

The list does not have to be static per-se. It just can't be created by a fixture. But don't let that stop you. You can put the code for defining and running `create_file` into a separate module, and just import it wherever you need it as a utility. That will obscure all the messy details and make your code look about as clean as it would with fixtures.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer but I already updated my other question: my problem here is that the `create_file_fixture` depends on other fixture and therefore can't be turned into a normal function... Guess I have to find something else or try to change the inner structure of my project...

Comment: You could also consider updating pytest. While it's nice to know how many tests you have up front, I'm not sure I see a good reason not to support at least lazy generators as parameters.

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50231627/python-pytest-unpack-fixture/56865893).

By design, this is not possible: the concept of "fixtures" is reserved to test execution, while the concept of "parameters" is reserved to test collection. Please see [my detailed answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56865893/7262247).