# Pytest: How to make sure a certain fixture is called first

Tags: python, pytest

I have some data in `a_file` which I need to parametrize my fixture with. Therefore, I wrote a helper function which returns `a_list` filled with the data from the file. Now I can easily parametrize my fixture via `@pytest.fixture(params=a_list)`. Seems straight forward, right?

The problem here is that `a_file` is generated by another fixture and it seems that pytest calls the helper which relies on that file before the file gets actually created by the fixture. Due to that behavior, a `FileNotFoundError` is raised.

My code looks like this:

```
def helper_returning_list_from_a_file():
    with open("a_file") as a_file:
        a_list = a_file.readlines()

    return a_list

@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def create_file_fixture(depends_on_other_fixtures):
    # create "a_file" here

@pytest.fixture(params=helper_returning_list_from_a_file())
def a_fixture_which_is_parametrized_with_data_from_a_file(request):
    return request.param

def test_which_uses(a_fixture_which_is_parametrized_with_data_from_a_file):
    assert False
```

**Addition:** The `create_file_fixture` needs to be a fixture and can't be transformed to a normal function because it depends on other fixtures.

---

#### What I already tried

The obvious solution is to make sure that the file gets created before the helper function which needs the file gets executed.

Therefore I

- added a dependency for `create_file_fixture` to the fixture which should get parametrized like so:

  ```
  @pytest.fixture(params=helper_returning_list_from_a_file())
  def a_fixture_which_is_parametrized_with_data_from_a_file(create_file_fixture, request):
      return request.param
  ```
- added the `autouse` flag to the fixture which creates the file like so:

  ```
  @pytest.fixture(scope="session", autouse=True)
  def create_file_fixture:
      # create "a_file" here
  ```

but pytest still calls the helper functions first which results in the same error as described above.

---

#### Question

How can I ensure that the `create_file_fixture` is executed first?

---

#### Possible solution

I think a possible solution would be to transform the helper function to a fixture, too. So I could easily add the dependency there which would dictate to pytest in which order the fixtures should be executed. This would look like so:

```
@pytest.fixture()
def fixture_returning_list_from_a_file(create_file_fixture):
with open("a_file") as a_file:
    a_list = a_file.readlines()

return a_list
```

This would solve my problem that the file doesn't exist but this also doesn't work for me because it leads to another problem which I described here: [parametrizing a test with a list returned from a fixture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52764279/pytest-how-to-parametrize-a-test-with-a-list-that-is-returned-from-a-fixture).

Comment: I have temporarily deleted my answer because it is blatantly wrong, as you pointed out. I will reinstate it once it is fixed.

Comment: Fixture params are evaluated before the fixtures themselves (which kinda makes sense), so creating the file in the fixture is too late. You can move the parametrization from fixture to test and apply indirect parametrization to `a_fixture_which_is_parametrized_with_data_from_a_file` there, but then you'll need to replicate the parametrize decorator at each test that uses that fixture, which is not quite what you want, I guess.

Comment: @hoefling. Looks like a great example of caching being at fault yet again :)

Comment: I've reinstated my answer, but you may not like it.

Comment: @MadPhysicist guess so :-) it's a pretty limited workaround anyway, works only until you start to chain fixtures.

Comment: @hoefling. Agreed. Until dynamic fixture parametrization becomes a thing, or yield fixtures allow true generators to run, it will have to do.

Comment: @hoefling could you post an answer with your decorator solution? I just have a few tests there and it would be an acceptable trade off to add the decorator to each function.

Comment: Eh, forget my proposal above - won't work since the `helper` must be called at import time anyway, when the decorators are resolved. So I see no way at all, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is not caused by `pytest` as such. It is caused by the fact that your helper function is called when the module is loaded by the Python interpreter, nominally before it gets to pytest.

Unfortunately, you can't yield more than one value from a fixture, and you can't parametrize over a lazy generator. The reason is that the full graph has to be computed before any fixtures or tests are run, which means knowing all the parameters up front, as explained in [this failed feature request](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/2155). [@Hoefling's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52765085/pytest-how-to-make-sure-a-certain-fixture-is-called-first/52765287#comment92454683_52765085) suggests one way to work around this. I would suggest a way that is probably less pytest-thonic, but should work nevertheless.

To ensure that your file is created up-front and that the entire list is available for parametrization, don't make it a fixture: just run it as part of your module loading code and make the list a module attribute. This won't prevent you from using it elsewhere. If multiple test modules use the same list, you can just place it into a separate non-test module and import it into the tests that need it.

```
def create_file_function():
    # create "a_file" here
    return 'a_file'

def helper_returning_list_from_a_file():
    with open(create_file_function()) as a_file:
        a_list = a_file.readlines()

    return a_list

a_list = helper_returning_list_from_a_file()

@pytest.fixture(params=a_list)
def a_fixture_which_is_parametrized_with_data_from_a_file(request):
    return request.param

def test_which_uses(a_fixture_which_is_parametrized_with_data_from_a_file):
    assert False
```

I think it is a bit more elegant/configurable to have `create_file_function` return the name of the file.

Given `a_file` that looks like:

```
ABC
DEF
```

The output of `pytest -v` looks like this:

```
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform linux -- Python 3.6.4, pytest-3.4.2, py-1.5.2, pluggy-0.6.0 -- /...
cachedir: .pytest_cache
rootdir: /..., inifile:
plugins: remotedata-0.2.0, pep8-1.0.6, openfiles-0.2.0, doctestplus-0.1.2, arraydiff-0.2
collected 2 items                                                              

52765085.py::test_which_uses[ABC\n] PASSED                                [ 50%]
52765085.py::test_which_uses[DEF] PASSED                                  [100%]

=========================== 2 passed in 0.01 seconds ===========================
```

Comment: I think the `yield` keyword is the key to success here! I'm already trying out some new solutions with generators. Thanks for the quick answer! But I'm still a little bit irritated because in your answer it looks like the whole list is passed to the test. But this isn't exactly what I need. I need the test to be executed for each value in the list. So if my list has 5 values, I need pytest to execute the test 5 times.

Comment: I updated my question: the `create_file_fixture` needs to be a fixture because it depends on other fixtures. So your current solution doesn't work for me...

Comment: By the way: I agree that it would be nicer to return a file name but in my case I'm not only creating an empty file, I also fill the file with a lot of data.